# nginx serving php files

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I am having trouble with a `php` test file on my nginx webserver.

For some reason, everytime I am trying to reach http://localhost/test.php I get the famous error `No input file specified`.

After opening the error logs, I see this message:

```
[error] FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: **/etc/nginx/html/**test.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: PUBLIC_IP, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1"
```

For some reason, the nginx service thinks my webroot directory is `/etc/nginx/html/`, which is obviously not where I want it to be.

This is my default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index   index.php index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
location /{

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
  }
# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php${
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

I can no find where this is configured. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: also i forgot to mention if i DO create path in /etc/nginx/html it work prefectly so i'm confident there aren't  any permission issues

Comment: Nginx is using the default root because you have not set a root within the scope of the `location ~ \.php$` block. Move the `root   /usr/share/nginx/html;` statement into the `server` block so that the same value is inherited by all of the `location` blocks.